# Calculating moving average with different codes and different sizes

Tags: r, moving-average

I have a data frame that contains data for different observations, where the observations are grouped with a unique code. As a reproducible example, here is how a simulated data looks like:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6)
mat1 <- matrix(runif(200),40)
mat1 <- cbind(v,mat1)
mat1 <-as.data.frame(mat1)
names(mat1) <- c('code','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5')
unq <- unique(mat1$code)
```

What I would like to do is to calculate an average for each observation, based on two previous and two future observations (you can think about this as a time series). So for example

`mat1$X1[3] = mean(mean(mat1$x1[1:5])`
`mat1$X1[4] = mean(mean(mat1$x1[2:6])`

and so on. I am able to do the calculation using a particular code (for example when `mat1$code==1`):

```
K <- data.frame(code=mat1$code,x1=rep(0,40),x2=rep(0,40),x3=rep(0,40),x4=rep(0,40),x5=rep(0,40))
for ( i in 3:(nrow(mat1)-2)){
  if(mat1$code[i]==unq[1]){
    K[i,2] <- mean(mat1[i-2:i+2,2]) 
  }
}
```

, but there are two things that I couldn't figure out:

(1) Since the actual dataset is much larger than the simulated one, how can I dynamically go through all the unique codes and do the calculation, noting that the first and last two observations of each unique code should be zero (and I will eventually get rid of them).

(2) The number of observations for each unique code is different, and some of them are less than 4, where in this case there can't be any calculation done for that code!

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @Adii Thanks, useful function, it makes the mean calculation easier, but I am still struggling to fulfill other requirements, like how to go dynamically through the unique codes, etc.

Comment: How about using `apply` function? Or `by`

Comment: @Adii_I am using apply. But I can't figure out how to do the calculation sequentially for each group of codes because they have different sizes.

Comment: @Adii_I have edited the question, it is hard coded to calculate for a particular unique code, and of course I can use `apply` to do this for all the columns. But I don't know how to intelligently do it for all the codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63188/discussion-between-adii-and-h-a).